# When is $x\mapsto |x|^{s-1}x$ a diffeomorphism?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Consider the function $f:B^n\rightarrow B^n$ from the disk to itself $$f(x)=\vert x\vert^{s-1}x$$ where $s>0$ and we are considering the euclidean norm (we define the function to be $0$ in the origin if $s<1$). This function defines a homemorphism from the disk to itself. My question is why if $f$ is a diffeomorphism, then $s=1$? This is part of an exercise in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds chapter 1.

Comment: If $f$ is a diffeomorphism, then 1. $Df\lvert_0$ exists, and 2. $Df\lvert_0$ is invertible.

Comment: Can you give a more explicit hint please?

Comment: Consider the case $n = 1$ (or, equivalently, the restriction of $f$ to a straight line through the origin). Sketch the graph for $0 < s < 1$, and for $s > 1$.

Comment: I can see intuitively why its not differentiable using the graphs, but can you tell me a more cuantitative (or formal) way to see this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quantitative way. Every differentiable function on $B^n$ is Lipschitz continuous: that is, there exists $L$ such that 
$$|f(a)-f(b)|\le L|a-b|,\quad a,b\in B^n \tag1$$
This follows from the  [Mean Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_in_several_variables).

If $f:B^n\to B^n$ is a diffeomorphism, then its inverse $f^{-1}$ is also Lipschitz, for the same reason. Hence, such $f$ is bi-Lipschitz, meaning there is $L$ such that 
$$L^{-1}|a-b|\le |f(a)-f(b)|\le L|a-b|,\quad a,b\in B^n \tag1$$

It remains to observe that $|f(x)-f(0)|/|x| = |x|^{s-1}$.